# Bash command in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I am trying to get the basename of filenames in Makefile; but it always fails: basename command does not work.
Here is my code:

```
    list = a.xlib b.lib
    all:
        for each_lib in $(notdir $(list)); \
            do \
                if [[ $$each_lib == *.xlib ]]; then \
                    *** Here I need to get the basename of $$each_lib to some variable, say base_lib *** \
                    cp -p $$base_lib-un.xlib ../../dist/lib/$$each_lib \
                else \
                    cp -p $$each_lib ../../dist/lib/$$each_lib \
                fi; \
            done;
```

If we can create a variable with the value of basename of each file in list, that would be perfect.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`$(basename ...)` is a make function. It cannot operate on shell variables, because they are expanded later than make commands. You can use the shells `$(...)` substitution, but you have to double the dollar sign, so makefile does not interpret it as a function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Please note that I need to change the base file names.
for example, a.xlib needs to be changed to a-un.xlib;
When I took a look the shell substitution, it does not have such functionality. May I ask you more comments on it?

Comment: You absolutely can do that sort of substitution in the shell but unless you need to base your transformation decisions based on shell results you should also be able to do it all in make directly and then run the shell commands on the translated results. Fully explaining your inputs, outputs and goals might help.

Answer (score 2):

See if one of the following options does what you want:

```
list = a.xlib b.lib

libs = $(filter-out %.xlib,$(list))
xlibs = $(filter %.xlib,$(list))

V ?= @

allsh:
    $(V)for each_lib in $(notdir $(libs)); do \
        echo cp -p $$each_lib ../../dist/lib/$$each_lib; \
    done;
    $(V)for each_lib in $(notdir $(xlibs)); do \
        base_lib="$$(basename $$each_lib .xlib)"; \
        echo cp -p $$base_lib-un.xlib ../../dist/lib/$$each_lib; \
    done;

xlibsstripped = $(patsubst %.xlib,%,$(xlibs))
allmake:
    $(V)for each_lib in $(notdir $(libs)); do \
        echo cp -p $$each_lib ../../dist/lib/$$each_lib; \
    done;
    $(V)for each_lib in $(notdir $(xlibsstripped)); do \
        echo cp -p $$each_lib-un.xlib ../../dist/lib/$$each_lib.xlib; \
    done;
```

Run with `make allsh/allmake V=` to see the commands being run.

Comment: `@` suppresses echoing of the commands. The commands run either way. `@` just controls whether you see the commands themselves (not their output). It is probably obvious for most people. This comment is for the rest (like me).

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is get the basenames, I'm surprised that `basename` doesn't work. (What version of Make are you using?) Note that it is a Make function, so it goes *outside* the rules:

```
list = a.xlib b.lib
BASES = $(basename $(list))
```

You can do it with other Make functions (note the colons):

```
list := a.xlib b.lib
list := $(patsubst %.lib,%,$(list))
list := $(patsubst %.xlib,%,$(list))
```

If what you really want to do is move the files and modify the names of the xlib files (`a-un.xlib` => `.../a.xlib`), there's an easier way:

```
targets := $(addprefix ../../dist/lib/,$(list))

all: $(targets)

../../dist/lib/%.lib: %.lib
    mv $< $@

../../dist/lib/%.xlib: %-un.xlib
    mv $< $@
```